# Сохранение и построение графиков из csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Почему то не показываются графики из папки с файлами csv, с данными. Файлов в папке много, нужно построить график к каждому файлу. При этом Дату можно не учитывать, т.к. в файле есть цифры от большего к меньшему - нужно так их и показать, от большего к меньшему. Получившиеся графики нужно сохранить в png, основываясь на названиях файлов.

```css
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

a = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/II/Downloads/*.csv',
                sep=',', encoding='latin1',
                parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True,
                index_col='Date')

for f in files:
    a = a.reset_index()
    a.columns = ['Date', 'Vol']
    a.plot(y='Vol')
    pic_fn = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + pic_ext
    plt.savefig(pic_fn)
```

Данные

```css
Date,Vol
2016-08-05,0.09999999999999964
2016-12-23,0.10000000000000142
2016-03-11,0.10000000000000142
2016-09-23,0.10000000000000142
2016-10-14,0.10999999999999943
2016-09-02,0.10999999999999943
2016-08-12,0.11999999999999922
2016-09-16,0.120000000000001
2016-05-20,0.129999999999999
2016-11-25,0.13000000000000078
2016-12-16,0.1399999999999988
2016-05-27,0.1399999999999988
2016-07-15,0.14000000000000057
2017-02-10,0.14000000000000057
2016-09-30,0.15000000000000036
2017-01-27,0.15999999999999837
2016-08-19,0.16000000000000014
2016-11-18,0.16999999999999993
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

def plot_graph(filename, figsize=(16, 10), pic_ext='.png'):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=['Vol'])
    # закоментируйте / удалите следующую строку если ваши данные _уже_ отсортированы
    df = df.sort_values('Vol')
    df = df.reset_index()[['Vol']]
    ticker = os.path.basename(f).rstrip('_data.csv')
    ax = df.plot(y='Vol', title=ticker, figsize=figsize)
    ax.get_figure().savefig(os.path.splitext(f)[0] + pic_ext)
    plt.close()

for f in glob.glob(r'D:\temp\.data\629509\*.csv'):
    plot_graph(f)
```

Пример результата:

```
D:\temp\.data\629509\AAPL_data.png
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Alex, можно поинтересоваться - что вам это даст? Вы увидите монотонно возрастающие графики для всех файлов, без привязки ко времени...

Comment: @Alex, поменял ответ. Хотя убывать такой график по определению не может - вы же сортируете данные...

Comment: @Alex, исправил ответ